# Prevent Long Text in Safari Select Dropdown From Overflowing to Multiple Lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have a standard `<Select>` dropdown that can have lengthy text in it. It behaves as I would expect in most browsers, with long text being cut off:

[image: Chrome dropdown]

In Safari though, long text overflows onto additional lines and the dropdown expands. How do I prevent this?

[image: Safari dropdown]

My dropdown has basic Bootstrap form-control styling:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I can't test this because I have no access to safari, but maybe some css like `select {  overflow-x: hidden; }` will work?

Comment: No luck with changing the overflow